# Java, GUI: Traffic Light, change colour method based on array values

Tags: java

I found this great Java Traffic Light code, which worked great:
https://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/19175-how-to-make-traffic-light-code-in-java.html

I want to implement something simular, but the lights should not change when a button is clicked. I want them to change based on an array with doubles, but I dont know how to send the change light command to the GUI.

I changed the code from the website and deleted everything I dont need.

The problem occurs in the test method, eclipse wants me to make the test method static but I want the method to return the command to switch lights and in the original code the method actionPerformed is not static as well

later on I will probably have to implement a delay between the light changes, so that it is seeable

Thank you very much!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TrafficLight extends JFrame  {


      Signal green = new Signal(Color.green);
      Signal yellow = new Signal(Color.yellow);
      Signal red = new Signal(Color.red);

    public TrafficLight(){
        super("Traffic Light");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        green.turnOn(false);
        yellow.turnOn(false);
        red.turnOn(true);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        p1.add(red);
        p1.add(yellow);
        p1.add(green);

        getContentPane().add(p1);

        pack();
        }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        TrafficLight tl = new TrafficLight();        
        tl.setVisible(true);

        double[] x = {
                -5,
                -6,
                143.18,
                146.8,
                144.61,
                142.3,
                144.22,

        };


                test(x);
    }    


 public void test(double[] testArray) {

        for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){

               if(testArray[i] <= 0){ //no data yet...
                  green.turnOn(false);            
                  yellow.turnOn(false);
                  red.turnOn(true);
              } else if(testArray[i] > 0){ 
                  red.turnOn(false);            
                  yellow.turnOn(false);
                  green.turnOn(true);

        }}}





}   
class Signal extends JPanel{

    Color on;
    int radius = 40;
    int border = 10;
    boolean change;

    Signal(Color color){
        on = color;
        change = true;
    }

    public void turnOn(boolean a){
        change = a;
        repaint();        
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        int size = (radius+border)*2;
        return new Dimension( size, size );
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        if (change){
            g.setColor( on );
        } else {
            g.setColor( on.darker().darker().darker() );
        }
        g.fillOval( border,border,2*radius,2*radius );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your main method is static so all methods it calls within its own object also need to be static. So in your code when you call:

```
 test(x);
```

You are not calling it on  a `TrafficLight` Object, you are calling it on the `TrafficLight` class.

What you want to do is call your method on the traffic light object you created:

```
tl.test(x);
```

Comment: of cause! Thank you so much!